# curl for ElasticSearch7.16: why there must be a blank character in request body?

Tags: json, powershell, elasticsearch, curl, command-line

I use  curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) in PowerShell 5.1.19041.610 to access Elastic Search 7.16, all run on my Win10 20H2.

This command line is successful:

```
PS D:> ./curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data " {\`"name\`":\`"John Doe\`"}"
```

And get output:

```json
{
  "_index" : "customer",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 17,
  "result" : "updated",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
  },
  "_seq_no" : 35,
  "_primary_term" : 13
}
```

You can notice there is a blank character just after the first double-quotation mark  in `--data " {`

But if I delete that blank character after the first double-quotation mark, just as `--data "{`, the command line get an error result:

```
PS D:> ./curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\`"name\`":\`"John Doe\`"}"
```

And get output:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse field [name] of type [text] in document with id '1'. Preview of field's value: ''"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse field [name] of type [text] in document with id '1'. Preview of field's value: ''",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 14]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 5:
Doe"}
    ^
```

Why this blank character is so important?

I had tried a lot times to get curl command run in Power Shell!

Answer (score 0):

This is issue coming from using PoweShell, no related to CURL or ElasticSearch. Curly braces `{` and `}` are special characters in PowerShell, which denote a variable usage and since they are also used for JSON, you have an issue sending JSON through PowerShell.

I do not know the exact syntax, but in one case, PowerShell is trying to match an opening brace to a closing brace. It looks like just adding a space before the brace will somehow escape it, in this case.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/powershell_brackets.htm

I recommend using another terminal or a tool like Postman to send these requests, instead of CURL with PowerShell.